# Autofac and Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces

Tags: msbuild, autofac, dependency-resolution

Visual Studio 2019 provides an *unannounced* 4.700.19.56404 version of `Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces` here:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces

Autofac accepts 1.1.0 or greater of this package.  However, if I try to update the Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces Nuget package to the latest version (5.0.0), I start running into problems where the package gets resolved to the 4.700.19.56404 version because:

```
21>  Dependency "Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51".
21>    Resolved file path is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll".
21>      Considered "C:\<repo-location>\bin\Debug\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll",
21>        but its name "Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51"
21>        didn't match the expected name "Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51".
```

And of course when trying to run, I get a runtime error because `Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces` cannot be loaded.

I guess the most obvious question is if there's a way around this via msbuild, e.g., some target that would resolve the dependency at build time to 5.0.0, not 4.700.19.56404.

Otherwise, I *think* this could be solved by having Autofac updating its `Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces` dependency to 5.0.0 over 1.1.0.  Not sure if this is feasible or not.

Comment: You should show your project file and, if applicable, web.config or app.config to show dependency versions and redirects you have in place. [In general, Autofac won't upgrade a dependency unless there's a technical reason](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/binding-redirect.html) so likely you'll need to take action at that level - adding an explicit reference to the updated package or adding a binding redirect.